# Customized multithreading: limiting number of tasks of some type to be executed in parallel, without limiting tasks of other types

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool

I have tasks of 3 types: `A, B, C`.

And I want to run those tasks in parallel in N threads. Let's suppose, that the list of tasks is the following:

```
A, B, C, B, C, A, B, C
```

Of course, I can achieve multithreading execution using `ExecutorService` But the problem is that I need **at most one task of type `C` to be executed at a time.** Other tasks of type `C` must be executed sequentially, but in parallel with tasks `A` and/or `B`.

For example 3-thread executor may be in any of following states:

```
A B C
A A A
A C B
B B C
B B B
B C
A C 
A B 
C  
...
```

(It is allowed to execute multiple tasks of type A or B at a time, but **at most one task** of type C must be executed at a time)

Is there some way to achieve this in Java?

***Update***

This is the One I have Comeup With Is this a correct way of doing this
Here I'm executing all the tasks via `ExecutorService` While execution I'll check If any other C Task is Running.If not I'll execute Else I'll add it to a Queue which will be dequeued on successful completion of any other Tasks and Also I check any C Task is running or Not

```
public class Test {

public void startExecution() {
    Queue<String> runQ = new LinkedList<>();
    ThreadPool exec = (ThreadPool) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(RunSettings.getRunSettings().getThreadCount());
    while (!runQ.isEmpty() && !SystemDefaults.stopExecution.get()) {
        String TaskName = runQ.remove();
        Task t = new Task(TaskName);
        exec.execute(t, TaskName);

    }
    exec.shutdown();
    if (exec.awaitTermination(RunSettings.getRunSettings().getExecutionTimeOut(), TimeUnit.MINUTES)) {
        System.out.println("[CONTROL: ALL TEST TASKS COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY.]");
    } else {
        System.out.println("[CONTROL: ALL THE TEST TASKS DID NOT COMPLETE SUCCESSFULLY IN STIPULATED TIME. FORCEFULLY FINALIZING.]");
        exec.shutdownNow();

    }
}
}
```

ThreadPool What I have created

```
public class ThreadPool extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

public ThreadPool(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
    super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue);
}

final String CTask = "TaskC";
Map<Runnable, String> TaskPool = new HashMap<>();
Queue<Runnable> TaskCList = new LinkedList<>();

@Override
protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
    super.afterExecute(r, t);
    if (TaskPool.containsKey(r)) {
        TaskPool.remove(r);
    }
    if (!TaskPool.containsValue(CTask) && !TaskCList.isEmpty()) {
        Runnable ieRun = TaskCList.remove();
        super.execute(ieRun);
        TaskPool.put(ieRun, CTask);
    }
}

public void execute(Runnable command, String TaskType) {
    if (TaskPool.containsValue(TaskType)
            && TaskType.equalsIgnoreCase(CTask)) {
        System.out.println("Another Instance of  " + CTask + " Running");
        TaskCList.add(command);
    } else {
        super.execute(command);
        TaskPool.put(command, TaskType);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: How come you have `AAA` , AB and `BBB` here without `C`?

Comment: @TheLostMind the list can have no C Tasks as well..In that Case that is the thing right

Comment: @SashaSalauyou If I create two seperate say for example I have 50 total tasks with 23 A 23 B 4 C .I want them in 3 threads then as per your case the A and B will always run in two threads and the thread allocated to C can't be reused.Or is it possible to increase the poolsize after execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for your support.Anyhow I came up with a solution which is working fine as of now

```
public class Test {

public void startExecution() {
Queue<String> runQ = new LinkedList<>();
ThreadPool threadPool = new ThreadPool(threadCount,timeOut);
while (!runQ.isEmpty()) {
    String TaskName = runQ.remove();
    Task t = new Task(TaskName);
    threadPool.execute(t, TaskName);

}
if (threadPool.awaitTermination(timeOut, TimeUnit.MINUTES)) {
    System.out.println("[CONTROL: ALL TEST TASKS COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY.]");
} else {
    System.out.println("[CONTROL: ALL THE TEST TASKS DID NOT COMPLETE SUCCESSFULLY IN STIPULATED TIME. FORCEFULLY FINALIZING.]");
    threadPool.shutdownNow();

}
}
}
```

ThreadPool Implementation

```
 public class ThreadPool extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

public ThreadPool(int threadCount, long keepAliveTime) {
    super(threadCount, threadCount, keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.MINUTES, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
}

final String CTask = "TaskC";
Map<Runnable, String> TaskPool = new HashMap<>();
Queue<Runnable> TaskCList = new LinkedList<>();

@Override
protected synchronized void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
    super.afterExecute(r, t);
    System.out.println(TaskPool.get(r) + "Finished");
    if (TaskPool.containsKey(r)) {
        TaskPool.remove(r);
    }
    if (TaskCList.isEmpty()) {
        super.shutdown();
    }
    if (!TaskPool.containsValue(CTask) && !TaskCList.isEmpty()) {
        if (super.getActiveCount() < super.getCorePoolSize()) {
            System.out.println("Trying to execute Other C Tasks");
            Runnable ieRun = TaskCList.remove();
            super.execute(ieRun);
            TaskPool.put(ieRun, CTask);
        }
    }
}

public synchronized void execute(Runnable command, String TaskType) {
    if (TaskPool.containsValue(TaskType)
            && TaskType.equalsIgnoreCase(CTask)) {
        System.out.println("Another Instance of TaskC Running");
        System.out.println("Added for future Execution");
        TaskCList.add(command);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Adding " + TaskType + " to execution");
        TaskPool.put(command, TaskType);
        super.execute(command);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is to create 2 executors: one single-threaded for tasks of type C, and another multithreaded for tasks of another types:

```
class ExecutorWrapper {
    private ExecutorService forC = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    private ExecutorService forAnother = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_NUMBER);

    public void acceptTask(Runnable r) {
        if (r instanceof TaskC) {
            forC.execute(r);
        } else {
            forAnother.execute(r);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, any tasks of type C will wait in `forC` executor internal queue until another tasks of such type complete.

If you don't want another executor to be created, you need to implement some sort of concurrency control, which is far more complex and hard to debug because of race conditions that may occur. I can propose solution draft, but without code:

1. Create a flag to indicate if another task C is already in execution, and a queue where another tasks C will wait
2. When task of type C arrives, check if another task C is in execution, if yes, add it into mentioned queue
3. On task C complete, send some sort of notification that task C have finished -- in order to take next task C from the mentioned queue and send it into Executor. If queue is empty, clear the flag to indicate that no tasks C are on execution now. Such notification can be implemented by wrapping task C with `Callable` and calling `Future#get` method that will block until task completes.

Comment: I was working on some other method which I've posted in the update.Can you go through that and see if it is correct or not.Also I'll check your suggestion as well

Comment: I think it's OK except one moment: you should implement better synchronization there, e. g. make `execute()` and `afterExecute()` methods synchronized. Otherwise race conditions may occur inside these methods.

Comment: Ok I'll try to do that

Answer (score -1):

It looks like all you need to do is make task C `synchronized`. Here's some test code that seems to demonstrate that that is enough - although an absence of failure does not always imply success.

The results clearly show A's and B's running in parallel but never C's.

```
static enum Task implements Callable<Void> {

    A,
    B,
    C {
                @Override
                public synchronized Void call() throws Exception {
                    if (running.get(this).get() != 0) {
                        System.out.println("FAIL!");
                    }
                    return super.call();
                }

            };

    // How many of each are running.
    static Map<Task, AtomicInteger> running = Stream.of(Task.values())
            .collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(
                            (t) -> t,
                            (t) -> new AtomicInteger(0),
                            (x, y) -> x,
                            () -> new EnumMap<Task, AtomicInteger>(Task.class)));

    // List all running tasks.
    private String runningList() {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        running.entrySet().stream().forEach((r) -> {
            if (r.getValue().get() != 0) {
                s.append(r.getKey()).append("=").append(r.getValue()).append(",");
            }
        });
        return s.toString();
    }

    static final Random random = new Random();

    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Running " + name() + " with " + runningList());
        // Mark me running.
        running.get(this).getAndIncrement();
        // Hang around for a bit.
        Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(1000));
        // Mark me not running.
        running.get(this).getAndDecrement();
        return null;
    }

}

// The pool.
static ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
// The tasks.
static Task[] tasks = new Task[]{Task.A, Task.B, Task.C, Task.B, Task.C, Task.A, Task.B, Task.C,};

public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    // Run 10 times.
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        pool.invokeAll(Arrays.asList(tasks));
    }
    pool.shutdown();
    pool.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Comment: What if A,C,C are passed into execution? A will be put into thread 1 and start, first C will be put into thread 2 and start, but another C which will be put by into available thread 3 will block, such making  thread 3 locked and not accessible for other A or B tasks until first C completes.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou - Correct - the thread will block and be parked until it is unblocked. This is the down-side of this option, although it is much simpler than using multiple executors. I am not suggesting this is a better solution than yours - just different.